# JSF 1.x generic exception handling

Tags: jsp, jsf, exception, jsf-1.2

If I have an exception in my business layer (e.g. a SQL exception in my JDBC connection bean), how can I propagate it with a custom message to a global `error.jsp` page?

Answer (score 19):

JSF 1.x doesn't provide any implicit error handling of this type, though you can redirect to an error page using navigation rules (assuming a form post)...

```
<navigation-case>
<description>
Handle a generic error outcome that might be returned
by any application Action.
</description>
<display-name>Generic Error Outcome</display-name>
<from-outcome>loginRequired</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/must-login-first.jsp</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

...or using a redirect...

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
String url = extContext.encodeActionURL(extContext
        .getRequestContextPath()
        + "/messages.faces");
extContext.redirect(url);
```

I recommend looking at the [JSF specification](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/reference/api/) for more details.

Error messages can be placed on the request scope/session scope/url parameters, as you like.

---

Assuming a Servlet container, you can use the usual [web.xml error page configuration](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html#bnaet).

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/errorPage.faces</location>
</error-page>
```

In your backing bean, you can wrap and throw your checked exceptions in [RuntimeException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html#RuntimeException(java.lang.Throwable))s.

Some JSF implementations/frameworks will catch these errors (Apache MyFaces/Facelets), so you'll have to [configure them not to](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Handling_Server_Errors).

Comment: this was an excellent response, I wish I could give you 10 points for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

The JSF 2 now has a mechanism for handling exceptions:

http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html

Answer (score 6):

I made ​​an error page in the site faces and put the stacktrace of the error
This code first put it in the web.xml

```
<error-page>
                <error-code>500</error-code>
                <location>/errorpage.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

While the jsf page had this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="EstilosOV.css" library="css" />
    <!-- <h:outputScript name="sincontext.js" library="scripts"/> -->

</h:head>
<h:body >
<table width="338" border="0" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">

    <tr bgcolor="#1D2F68">
      <td colspan="4" height="35" class="TablaHeader2"> PLAN SEGURO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="#FDF2AA">
    <td colspan="4"  class="HeaderExcepcion">
      <h:graphicImage library="images" name="errormark.jpg"/>
      <font size="5px" color="#CC0000" >Error de ejecución</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
    <td colspan="3" class="anuncioWarning2">Ocurrio un error al realizar la operación, favor de intentarlo nuevamente, si el error aún se presenta, favor de notificarlo a soporte técnico al 5147-31-00 extensión 6893</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="17" colspan="3" class="TablaHeader2"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
    <h:form id="formerror">
        <h:inputHidden id="valuestack" value="#{errorDisplay.stackTrace}"></h:inputHidden>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Note that motif lets you debug the stacktrace for an reazon know which is the exception in the hidden field.
Let's see how the class is defined recovers StackTrace

```
public class ErrorDisplay implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6032693999191928654L;
    public static Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(ErrorDisplay.class);

    public String getContacto() {
        return "";
    }

    public String getStackTrace() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
        Throwable ex = (Throwable) requestMap.get("javax.servlet.error.exception");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
        fillStackTrace(ex, pw);
        LOG.fatal(writer.toString());

        return writer.toString();
    }

    private void fillStackTrace(Throwable ex, PrintWriter pw) {
        if (null == ex) {
            return;
        }

        ex.printStackTrace(pw);

        if (ex instanceof ServletException) {
            Throwable cause = ((ServletException) ex).getRootCause();

            if (null != cause) {
                pw.println("Root Cause:");
                fillStackTrace(cause, pw);
            }
        } else {
            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();

            if (null != cause) {
                pw.println("Cause:");
                fillStackTrace(cause, pw);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and already attached as you finish this bean definition in the file facesconfig

```
<managed-bean>
            <description>
                Bean que sirve para llenar la especificacion de un error. Stacktrace 
            </description>
            <managed-bean-name>errorDisplay</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>mx.com.tdc.datos.page.bean.ErrorDisplay</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>
```

And I hope that this will serve

Answer (score 3):

The general way to display error message to the user in JSF is to use FacesMessage:

On Java side:

```
...
if (errorOccurred) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("An error occurred blabla..."));
}
```

and in the JSF (JSP or XHTML) page, simply use the `<h:messages/>` component in your page in order to display the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
```

in jour jsp/jsf page. In error.jsp, jou would have:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

isErrorPage="true" will give your page another implicit object: exception (the same way you already have request and response on jsp page). You can then extract message from exception.

[Additional details](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro4.html)

Answer (score 1):

I came to same problem and found link describing how you can use ExceptionHandler in JSF2:

http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2010/09/jsf-2-exception-handling.html