# Error handling page with backing bean problem with JSF/Facelets

Tags: jsf, error-handling, facelets

Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460596/jsf-generic-exception-handling/6110101#6110101) I made an error page like this:

In faces-config.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errore500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

....

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>errore</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>it.jlp.prometheus.modello.Errore</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

... the page errore500.xhtml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="JLP" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stile.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="icons/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <title>Prometheus - Error 500</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h:form>

....

 <br/><h:inputTextarea style="width: 100%;" rows="20" readonly="true"
                                          value="#{errore.stackTrace}" />

 ....
```

...and the class Errore

```
public class Errore implements Serializable {

private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Errore.class);

public String getStackTrace() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    Throwable ex = (Throwable) requestMap.get("javax.servlet.error.exception");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
    fillStackTrace(ex, pw);
    logger.info("****** getStackTrace executed ");
    return writer.toString();
}

private void fillStackTrace(Throwable ex, PrintWriter pw) {
    if (null == ex) {
        return;
    }
    ex.printStackTrace(pw);
    if (ex instanceof ServletException) {
        Throwable cause = ((ServletException) ex).getRootCause();
        if (null != cause) {
            pw.println("Root Cause:");
            fillStackTrace(cause, pw);
        }
        } else {
        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();

        if (null != cause) {
            pw.println("Cause:");
            fillStackTrace(cause, pw);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, when I cause intentionally an ecception (a ClassCastException) in another part of application, it redirect me to this page but, by putting a debug print log in the backing bean class I saw that this is never instantiated, thus the text area doesn't get populated.
Why the backing bean is never instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

The location

```
<location>/errore500.xhtml</location>
```

must match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`.

So if it is for example mapped on

```
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

then you need to set the location to

```
<location>/errore500.jsf</location>
```

Comment: I have in web.xml this piece of configuration:

 `<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    ...
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Should I change location with errore500.faces?

Comment: Yes, the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't work. Could be something else? Maybe faces configuration stuff?